# Maximum number of recipient in Java Mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am working on a project which involves sending emails using Java. We are using the JavaMailx Module( had to be imported). **I would like to know that what is the maximum number of recipients to whom we can send our email ( Mime message consisting of message, subject , attachments ) in one go.** What is the limit on the number of recipients who can be emailed together. I have searched for this online and on stackoverflow and there are no clear answers.
We are using the gmail smtp server to send emails from gmail accounts and yahoo smtp server to send mails from the yahoo accounts. **Do the maximum number of recipients depend upon these smtp servers as well ? If so what is the default limits on them ?** From personal experience i can tell that my academic email allows sending mails to multiple people in one go ( whole mailing lists consisting of 200-300 people). I am not sure about how it works in the back end, if they go in small groups of recipients or in total.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No limits are specified in the API documentation, so the limits will be those inherent in the implementation (i.e. memory).

Also, it is likely the sending and/or receiving SMTP server limits will be reached before any limits imposed by the implementation.

Comment: Thank you Jim, do you have any idea what limits are set up by the gmail smtp server ? From a friend i got to know that they had some problems in sending mails to over 20 recipients, but i dont think they were using java. And as far as the smpt server is concerned my mail domain is mailadd@iiitd.ac.in we can send mails to 300-400 people from out accounts. Can the normal emailadd@gmail.com mail users send to similar number of people or they have a limit ?

Comment: I don't and that would be a question for Gmail support, not SO.  It is likely they impose different limits based on your IP address and other metrics.  If you attempt this from a dynamic IP such as one assigned by an ISP like Comcast or Time-Warner, you may not be able to send any emails, or may be limited to a handful of recipients.

Comment: Oh ok I will read into this further. Thank you for your help Jim, it has been guiding ! :)